# Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i rolslaunch the  file of one node  but got the error message as following.

```
[FATAL] [1460819328.350552093]: ASSERTION FAILED
    file = /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h
    line = 102
    cond = false
    message = 
[FATAL] [1460819328.350660121]: Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher
[FATAL] [1460819328.350700112]:
```

i am doubt that publisher.h has some error, but it is OK when i rolslaunch anothee file of another node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232068/call-to-publish()-on-an-invalid-publisher/) by [jeping123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/26611/jeping123456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-04-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-16**:
Please format console copy/pastes with the *Preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it). Otherwise the error text gets filtered, and it's not visible.

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-05-18**:
In my case, the issue was caused by calling the `shutdown()` method from the publisher

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has the publisher been initialised? This is an error I recently ran into, and from memory, this error will be thrown if you try to publish on a publisher that has been declared as a class variable, but not initialised either in the constructor or in the function body. If it's initialised in the constructor and the instance of the class is in a different scope to the call to publish(), that will also cause this error (say if you construct your instance in your main loop but try to call publish from a subscriber callback).

---

Originally posted by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) with karma: 153 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ai-shwarya](https://answers.ros.org/users/25300/ai-shwarya/) on 2016-12-05**:
Thanks! This helped.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem before. In my case, I call a function that has ros publisher in it before declare pub = n.advertise ... in main()

Maybe this will help you

---

Originally posted by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) with karma: 150 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publisher must be initialized. The following sample code to publish IMU message might be helpful:

```
void pubIMU(double tsIMU, double gyro_x, double gyro_y, double gyro_z, double acc_x, double acc_y, double acc_z)
{
       sensor_msgs::Imu imuMsg;
    
//  imuMsg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

    imuMsg.header.frame_id = "imu"; //
    
    imuMsg.angular_velocity.x = gyro_x;
    imuMsg.angular_velocity.y = gyro_y;
    imuMsg.angular_velocity.z = gyro_z;

    imuMsg.linear_acceleration.x = acc_x;
    imuMsg.linear_acceleration.y = acc_y;
    imuMsg.linear_acceleration.z = acc_z;

    pub_imu.publish(imuMsg);
}
void readCSV(const string &strPath2Dataset)
{
       // some function to extract info from a sample csv file:
       // ....
       // ....
       // ....

       pubIMU(timeStampIMU[i], gyro_X[i], gyro_Y[i], gyro_Z[i], acc_X[i], acc_Y[i], acc_Z[i]);
       // ^^^^^real function I'd like to publish^^^^^, ****modify based on your own need!!!
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "imuPub");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    // all your publisher must be defined in the very beginning:
    pub_imu     = nh.advertise      <sensor_msgs::Imu>                  ("/imu_raw"     ,1);
    pub_cam     = nh.advertise      <geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>        ("/cam_pose"    ,1);
    pub_path    = nh.advertise      <nav_msgs::Path>                    ("/cam_path"    ,1);

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        readCSV("test.csv");
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) with karma: 165 on 2018-12-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raghav](https://answers.ros.org/users/79472/raghav/) on 2021-10-27**:
I tried the same. Still facing the error. Can you help me?